# Is 0 a real number?

Tags: real-numbers

I am just curious if 0 is a real number. The definition of a real number is all rational and irrational numbers. And the def definition for rational number is that "$\mathbb{Q}={a\div b|a,b\in\mathbb{Z}}$".
But in done say that $0$ is a whole number and some day that it is not.
In some websites some say that $0$ is a real number, and in some not.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: $0=0/b$ is rational, hence real. And $0$ definitely is an integer, so $0\in \Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}$, the set of rational numbers, is the set $\{\frac{a}{b}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}, b\neq 0\}$

$\Rightarrow 0=\frac0b$ is a rational number, where $0,b\in\mathbb{Z}, b\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

By $\mathbb{Z}$'s definition, $0\in\mathbb{Z}$. So then for all $b\in\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$, we have that $0=\frac{0}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}$. Because of this, then $\frac{0}{b}=0\in\mathbb{R}$. To be said, $0$ is a real number.

Comment: Thank you all. :-)